# Stop middleware pipeline execution in KOA

Tags: node.js, generator, middleware, koa

I would like to ask if there is a way to stop the execution of the middleware pipeline in KOA?

In the example below, I have a middleware that would somehow validate something. How could I re-code my middleware to stop the execution when validation fails?

```
var koa = require('koa');
var router = require('koa-router')();
var app = koa();

app.use(router.routes());

// middleware
app.use(function *(next){
  var valid = false;
  if (!valid){
    console.log('entered validation')
    this.body = "error"
    return this.body; // how to stop the execution in here
  }
});

// route
router.get('/', function *(next){
  yield next;
  this.body = "should not enter here";
});


app.listen(3000);
```

I could actually change my route to this:

```
router.get('/', function *(next){
  yield next;
  if(this.body !== "error")
    this.body = "should not enter here";
});
```

But is there a better way? Or I'm missing something?

> This is just an example, in reality my middleware might put a property
>   in the body (this.body.hasErrors = true) and the route would read from
>   that.

Again, how could I stop the execution in my middleware, so that my routes would not be executed? In Express I think you could do a response.end (not sure about this though).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Middleware is executed in the sequence you add them to the app.
You can choose to either yield to downstream middleware or send a response early (errors etc).
So the key to stoping middleware flow is to not yield.

```
app.use(function *(next){
  // yield to downstream middleware if desired
  if(doValidation(this)){
    yield next;
  }
  // or respond in this middleware 
  else{
    this.throw(403, 'Validation Error');
  }
});

app.use(function *(next){
  // this is added second so it is downstream to the first generator function
  // and can only reached if upstream middleware yields      
  this.body = 'Made it to the downstream middleware'
});
```

#### Edit for clarity:

below I've modified your original example to make it work the way I think you are intending.

```
var koa = require('koa');
var router = require('koa-router')();
var app = koa();

// move route handlers below middleware
//app.use(router.routes());

// middleware
app.use(function *(next){
  var valid = false;
  if (!valid){
    console.log('entered validation')
    this.body = "error"
    // return this.body; // how to stop the execution in here
  }
  else{
    yield next;
  }
});

// route
router.get('/', function *(next){
  // based on your example I don't think you want to yield here
  // as this seems to be a returning middleware
  // yield next;
  this.body = "should not enter here";
});

// add routes here
app.use(router.routes());

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Hi James, thanks for your response.. First of all, I would like to say a big thanks for your blog posts http://knowthen.com/.. it helped me a lot... Back to my question.. :).. Actually my middleware didn't do any yield.. only the route (yield to the downstream).. do you have any idea on how to do this? or I'm doing it very2x wrong...

Comment: Hi James, thanks... my route should not have a yield - this is the thing I'm doing wrong.. thanks for pointing this one out...

Comment: @daxsorbito couple things: middleware that always returns, shouldn't have yield as you mentioned, validating middleware should have a conditional yield (your original example didn't have this) and the order in which you add middleware is significant.  You were adding your returning middleware before your validating middleware so flow started with your returning middleware, and never would reach your validating middleware.